# pyautogui hotkey combination is not working

Tags: pyautogui, hotkeys

I was trying going through an entire row by using pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','shift','right') in ms excel. i have also tried using pyautogui.hold, pyautogui.keydown but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to select all rows containing data in ms excel using pyautogui function in python but when i try pyauotogui.hotkey('ctrl','shift','right'), it is not working

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (uses pynput instead of pyautogui):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl_l):
    with keyboard.pressed(Key.shift):
        keyboard.press(Key.right)
        keyboard.release(Key.right)
```